# Why Sympy.solve does not provide every solution to the equation?

Tags: python, sympy

I have tried to solve `100n^2 -2^n = 0` by using `sympy.solve()`. `Sympy.solve()` found only two positive solutions while the equation (`100n^2-2^n`) has actually three solutions (one negative, two positives). I'm curious why `sympy.solve()` is unable to find every solution to the equation. Below is my code. Any insight please?

```
import sympy as sy

n = sy.Symbol('n')
sol = sy.solve(100 * (n ** 2) - (2 ** n), dict =True)
print(sol)
```

```
Result: [{n: -2*LambertW(-log(2)/20)/log(2)}, {n: -2*LambertW(-log(2)/20, -1)/log(2)}]
```

Comment: I tried your snippet and it returned me 3 solutions [{n: -2*LambertW(-log(2)/20)/log(2)}, {n: -2*LambertW(log(2)/20)/log(2)}, {n: -2*LambertW(-log(2)/20, -1)/log(2)}]

Comment: That's weird. I ran my codes on Google Colab. Could it be the reason why it went wrong?

Comment: The default version of SymPy in Google Colab is 1.1.1. Later versions of SymPy gives 3 solutions. To upgrade, type `!pip install sympy --upgrade` and restart the runtime.

Comment: Oh my god. I've got 3 solutions after I updated sympy. Thank you a lot, guys.